# Attach a psql session to a running transaction

Tags: transaction, psql

Is it possible to open a psql session inside a currently existing transaction?

I'd like to be able to do this for debugging purposes. The idea would be to break into a debugger in my program, attach psql to the transaction that the program is currently in, and interactively inspect the state of the database as seen by the program at that point.

I can't find any way to do anything like this so I suspect it might be impossible, but it would be nice to have a definitive answer.